# Eagle 7.7.0 - PCB: how export pin names to *.png

Tags: eaglecad

I downloaded Eagle 7.7.0, opened a schema and PCB in it, and I need to **export the PCB layout** to image ("print to *.png").

File/Export/Image does something that is almost good - export layers depending on what I select (the icon with 3 colored squares - layers). It prints out, BUT... I can't figure out how to set it up to also print the pin names. On the screen, I can clearly see a pad with 14 on top and GND on bottom of the hole, but in the resulting image, only 14 is in the middle.

In an extreme case - I hide all layers - I see nothing. I enable 17 - Pads - I see pads with a number and name - I print it, and I only see the pads with the number in the middle, the name is missing. (At resolutions 600 and 2,400, it's the same, just jagged differently)

(I can count the pins on my fingers from the edge; I don't need that, but I mainly want GND and other names)

It is rather large PCB (and there is more similar project I need to convert) so it does not fit on one screen in resolution, where all details are clearly visible. It needs zooming and then the parts are big enought to have all details, but it would take more printscreens .

**I wouldn't like to do it by stitching together a series of screenshots in a graphic editor.**

Does anyone know what I should click on to print the pin names? I want it as documentation of what is there (so I can track it on the board); I'll do new plans differently anyway (in KiCad).

Comment: just to be 100% clear: we're talking about the PCB, not the schematic, right?

Comment: Take a screenshot (Alt-PrintScreen on MS Windows)?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes, about the PCB.

Comment: @ChrisKnudsen 

It is rather large PCB (and there is more similar project I need to convert) so it does not fit on one screen in resolution, where all details are clearly visible. It needs zooming and then the parts are big enought to have all details, but it would take more printscreens .